# manager.dict() "skipping" to update some values in multiprocessing ~ Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, multiprocessing

In multiprocessing, I wanted to update `manager.dict()`, it's being updated... But some data are getting skipped while updating? What can be done?
It's something similar to this...

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

manager = Manager()
a = manager.dict()
a['url_info'] = manager.list()


def parse_link(link):
    # parse link, pared_info returns dict
    pared_info = link_parser(link)
    a['url_info'].append(pared_info)

# Links contains a lot of url that needs to be parsed.
links = ["https://url.com/1","https://url.com/2", "https://url.com/3"]


processes = []

for link in links:
    p = Process(target=parse_link, args=link,))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

`link_parser()` is a function that returns a dictionary, which contains the information about the scraped/parsed webpage.

```
> print(list(a['url_info']))
> ['#info_1', '#info_3']
```

Here the multiprocessing program skipped updating `#info_2` in the list (aka Array). Help me please

Comment: A number of potential issues here. I would start by looking into the implementation of *link_parser()*. It may be that an exception arose (which wasn't caught) and the process therefore failed

Comment: Nope bro, link_parser(link) is literally good, also for any expectation there is exception handling as well. So, only issue is with multiprocessing

Comment: The *args* keyword for Process has to refer to an iterable. Try: *p = Process(target=parse_link, args=(link,)))*. Also, instead of a loop in your main program you could consider using the *map()* feature of ProcessPoolExecutor

Comment: How often does the problem occur? Every run, or very rarely? 
Can you post also `link_parser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that demonstrates an improved structure for what you're trying to do.

Obviously it doesn't have the detail of your *link_parser()* but you'll get the point.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Manager
from functools import partial

LINKS = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
KEY = 'url_info'


def parse_link(a, link):
    a[KEY].append(link)


def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        a = manager.dict()
        a[KEY] = manager.list()
        with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(partial(parse_link, a), LINKS)
        print(a[KEY])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```